# How to dynamically call a function in a shared library?

Tags: dll, rust, shared-libraries, external

I have a Rust project, set as an executable. I am trying to call an external shared library, also written in Rust, dynamically. I have the external library compiled on release, and I have tried both crate types `cdylib` and `dylib`.

I am using the crate [libloading](https://docs.rs/libloading/0.7.0/libloading/), which claims to be able to dynamically load shared library functions, as long as they only use primitive arguments. I keep getting this error when I try to run my code using this crate.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: GetProcAddress { source: Os { code: 127, kind: Other, message: "The specified procedure could not be found." } }', src\main.rs:14:68
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

---

**main.rs/main():**

```
    let now = Instant::now();

    unsafe {
        let lib = libloading::Library::new(
            "externtest.dll").unwrap();
        let foo3: Symbol<extern fn(i32) -> i32> = lib.get(b"foo").unwrap();

        println!("{}", foo(1));
    }

    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed: {:?}", elapsed);
```

**lib.rs:**

```
pub extern "C" fn foo3(i:i32) -> i32{
    i
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your library function is called `"foo3"`, but you're trying to load the symbol `"foo"`.

Second, the library function's symbol may not match it's name due to mangling. You need to tell the compiler not to do that with the [`#[no_mangle]`](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/interoperability/rust-with-c.html#no_mangle) attribute:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn foo(i: i32) -> i32 {
    i
}
```

Third, this is mostly a stylistic choice, but I'd specify the ABI `extern "C"` when defining your symbol. Even though [`extern` with no epecified ABI uses the `"C"` ABI](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/external-blocks.html#abi), I've found it better to be explicit.

```
use libloading::{Library, Symbol};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let lib = Library::new("externtest.dll").unwrap();
        let foo = lib
            .get::<Symbol<extern "C" fn(i32) -> i32>>(b"foo")
            .unwrap();

        println!("{}", foo(1));
    }
}
```

The above should work without issue.

Comment: Thank you! For the problems with the function name, that is because with all the things I tried to get it working, I messed some stuff up. Also, I was sure that by using extern, you did not have to use #[no_mangle], but I guess I was wrong. I thought I had read that in an accepted pull request on Rust's GitHub.

Comment: @Duel I believe `pub extern "C"` implying `#[no_mangle]` has been *proposed*, but I don't think it had actually been changed. Of course, let me know if you find a PR to the contrary.

Comment: @Duel they're currently two separate concerns: `extern fn` is about the ABI, and `no_mangle` is about the symbol's name. You may have a use for one without the other e.g. if you need a C-compatible callback but will not be exposing the symbol, keeping it mangled is probably safer. It *is* a bit confusing because `extern {}` *blocks* use the names as-is. There have been a proposals to e.g. make `pub extern fn` implicitly unmangled (and keep `extern fn` mangled), but they're breaking changes so....

Comment: (it's also confusing because C++'s `extern "C"` is Rust's `no_mangle`)

Comment: Yeah, I see why they would be hesitant to change that.